# Look for a special example: $a(n) < b(n)$, but $\lim a(n) > \lim b(n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, discrete-mathematics

I understand that there are already proofs that show if $a(n) < b(n)$, then $\lim a(n) < \lim b(n)$ as $n$ approaches infinity

But the question asks to find a special case in which even if $a(n) < b(n)$, yet $\lim a(n) > \lim b(n)$ as $n$ approaches infinity. I wonder if that is even possible?

Thank you very much beforehand!

Answer (score 2):

Error: If $a(n)<b(n)$ for all $n$ (or for all but finitely many $n$) then $\lim a(n)\le \lim b(n).$ The limits may be equal. E.g. if $a(n)=0$ for every $n,$ and $b(n)=1/n.$

But this means there can be no "special case", i.e. no exceptions.

If $\lim a(n)=a>b,$ and $a(n)\le b(n)$ for all but finitely many $n$, let $(a-b)=2\epsilon.$ Then $\epsilon>0. $

Let $S=\{n: a(n)>b(n) \}.$ Let $T=\{n: a(n)\le a-\epsilon \}.$ Then $S$ and $T$ are finite, so $S\cup T$ is finite.

If $n\not\in S\cup T$ then $$b(n)-b=(b(n)-a(n))+(a(n)-a)+(a-b)\ge$$ $$\ge (a(n)-a)+(a-b)>$$ $$>(-\epsilon)+(a-b)=\epsilon.$$ So for all but finitely many $n$ (i.e. for all $n\not\in S\cup T)$ we have $$|b(n)-b|=b(n)-b>\epsilon$$ with $\epsilon >0$, so $b(n)$ $cannot$ converge to $b.$